# How to create a direct call from the conference?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have a call from the phone to the agent. Then I implement the worm transfer by creating the conference. I move both phone and agent to the conference room and I invite another agent.
Let`s look at the happy situation. The second agent enter the conference and the first agent finish the call. So now I need to setup a direct call between the phone and the second agent.

I think that I could put the phone call to the queue an make the agent to pick it up.
But maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There indeed is a better solution to achieve your requirement. You should be able to use "Conference Participant" REST API to make an outbound call to the desired participant and have them in the conference as soon as they answerIt’s a declarative API for specifying the action to “create an outbound call and connect it to a conference.” Instead of creating an outbound call and then having Twilio fetch TwiML once the call connects, calls created with this API are connected to a conference immediately on creation.

As you would expect, agents can now hear the state of the outbound call (like ringing or disconnect messages) while still being in a Conference.

An example request for this API is below:

```html
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC25e16e9a716a4a1768c7c83f58e30482/Conferences/AgentConf12/Participants' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+15624421212' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180021216' \
--data-urlencode 'EarlyMedia=true \
-u AC25e16e9a716a4a1768c7c83f58e30482:[Token]
```

You can read more about this in the [Docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but actually I need to implement another thing. I already have a conference with two participants (a phone caller and an agent). Now I need to stop the conference and start the direct call between them.